# Python: referencing class object list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, member-access

I am fairly new to python. I have tried to define a class, I then want to create an instance from a file, then refer to specific pieces of it, but cannot seem to. This is Python 3.3.0

Here's the class....

```
class Teams():

    def __init__(self, ID = None, Team = None, R = None, W = None, L = None):
        self._items = [ [] for i in range(5) ]
        self.Count = 0


    def addTeam(self, ID, Team, R=None, W = 0, L = 0):
        self._items[0].append(ID)
        self._items[1].append(Team)
        self._items[2].append(R)
        self._items[3].append(W)
        self._items[4].append(L)
        self.Count += 1

    def addTeamsFromFile(self, filename):
        inputFile = open(filename, 'r')
        for line in inputFile:
            words = line.split(',')
            self.addTeam(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4])

    def __len__(self):
        return self.Count
```

Here's the code in Main

```
startFileName = 'file_test.txt'
filename = startFileName

###########
myTestData = Teams()

myTestData.addTeamsFromFile(startFileName)
```

sample data in file

```
100,AAAA,106,5,0
200,BBBB,88,3,2
300,CCCC,45,1,4
400,DDDD,67,3,2
500,EEEE,90,4,1
```

I think I am good to here (not 100% sure), but now how do I reference this data to see... am i not creating the class correctly? How do I see if one instance is larger than another...

ie, `myTestData[2][2] > myTestData[3][2]` <----- this is where I get confused, as this doesn't work

Comment: Don’t forget to close your file handle after using it; or use the `with open() as f:` syntax to make Python do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a `Team` class like this :

```
class Team():
    def __init__(self, ID, Team, R=None, W = 0, L = 0)
      # set up fields here
```

Then in `Teams`

```
class Teams():
   def __init__(self):
       self._teams = []
   def addTeam (self, ID, Team, R=None, W = 0, L = 0)
       team = Team (ID, Team, R=None, W = 0, L = 0)
       self._teams.append (team)
```

---

Now If i got it right you want to overwrite the `>` operator's behaviour.

To do that overload `__gt__(self, other)` [[link]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

So it will be

```
class Team ():
   # init code from above for Team

    def __gt__ (self, otherTeam):
        return self.ID > otherTeam.ID # for example
```

Also be sure to convert those strings to numbers because you compare strings not numbers. Use `int` function for that.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem you're running into is that your code to access the team data doesn't account for your `myTestData` value being an object rather than a list. You can fix it by doing:

```
myTestData._items[2][2] > myTestData._items[3][2]
```

Though, if you plan on doing that much, I'd suggest renaming `_items` to something that's obviously supposed to be public. You might also want to make the `addTeamsFromFile` method convert some of the values it reads to integers (rather than leaving them as strings) before passing them to the `addTeam` method.

An alternative would be to make your `Teams` class support direct member access. You can do that by creating a method named `__getitem__` (and `__setitem__` if you want to be able to assign values directly). Something like:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self._items[index]
```

@Aleksandar's answer about making a class for the team data items is also a good one. In fact, it might be more useful to have a class for the individual teams than it is to have a class containing several. You could replace the `Teams` class with a list of `Team` instances. It depends on what you're going to be doing with it I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I have combined both of the suggestions. First a class aTeam() (there were too many items named 'Team') then a class Teams()... I can add from a file. I added a method __getitem__, but how do I call that from main? everything I try says it is undefined.

Comment: @user1889575: The `__getitem__` method is called automatically when you do `obj[index]`. That is, your original code (like `myTestData[2][2]`) should work.

Comment: Thanks. I had to create `__getitem__` for both classes.

Comment: Oh, I see. yeah, if you're still storing the data in a list inside the `aTeam` class, then you'd need a `__getitem__` method there too. However, I'd suggest using attributes instead. That is, put the `W` value in `self.W` rather than in a certain index in a list. Then you'd do `myTestData[2].W` (or whatever).